# Use Microsoft.Office.Interop on server without MS Office installation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office-interop, rdlc, excel-interop, word-interop

I wanted to know that is it necessary to install Microsoft Office on server in order to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word ?

**In short, what are the dependencies of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.**

I have searched on web a lot and have some mixed responses but none of the methods given helped me.

**I have noticed that RDLC report inside report Viewer can be saved to Excel,Word,PDFs, etc without MS Office installation.**

**So using same logic,is there a way a way to generate Excel and word file using Microsoft.Office.Interop without installing Microsoft Office on server just by registering some dlls ?**

I have been stuck on this for 2 months.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you try: [How to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel on a machine without installed MS Office?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4378c7c-fc5e-4d78-9821-c2644c71763f/how-to-use-microsoftofficeinteropexcel-on-a-machine-without-installed-ms-office?forum=exceldev)

Comment: Yes, I have seen that.
All I am saying is that if it is possible for RDLC report to generate EXCEL,WORD files without MS Office installtion then it should be the case with Microsoft.Office.Interop.

Comment: Those interop libraries are supposed to be used only with a microsoft office installed, but as you noticed the RDLC is able to generate different files using its render method, supported formats include Excel, PDF, Word, and Image as stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms252172(v=vs.100)

Comment: @A.Lion Can't that same logic be extended in this case by registering some dlls of MS Office which are used by Microsoft.Office.Interop  ?

Comment: Nope, it is not a matter of logic but design. Interops are built to interact with Ms-Office, the user application, so despite I made myself use of its ancestor, OLE COM interop from a vb6 application running on a Windows server 2003 it is not suggested to use them in a server environment. 
In fact the solution will be prone to get stuck with an invisible office messagebox unless your code is bulletproof.
In order to work with office files on a server there are other options, like NPOI Apache or Open-xml sdk, made by Microsoft itself

Answer (score 1):

There is no way using Office interop assemblies without installing Microsoft Office on the machine. Interop assemblies are used to marshal your property and method calls to the COM server (unmanaged world).

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) which doesn't require any Office installation on the machine. Or just consider any third-party components designed for the server-side execution.